# Check for only digits in VB.NET String

Tags: vb.net

I want to run a check on a String right before I append it to a StringBuilder to make sure only numeric characters are in the string. What's a simple way to do that?

Comment: Define numeric character? Do you only consider 0 to 9, or hexa decimal character too? Is `0x87` valid?

Comment: Yup only 0-9 i need to keep track of

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Integer.TryParse() it will return true if there are only digits in the string. Int32 max value is 2,147,483,647 so if your value is less then that then your fine.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

You can also use Double.TryParse() which has a max value of 1.7976931348623157E+308 but it will allow a decimal point.

If your looking to get the value that isnt an integer you can always go through the string one at a time

```
string test = "1112003212g1232";
        int result;
        bool append=true;
        for (int i = 0; i < test.Length-1; i++)
        {
            if(!Int32.TryParse(test.Substring(i,i+1),out result))
            {
                //Not an integer
                append = false;
            }
        }
```

If append stays true then the string is an integer. Probably a more slick way of doing this but this should work.

Comment: As long as the string isn't larger than the max Int32.

Comment: That won't work if the string is too long resulting in the integer overflow

Comment: Pretty much I just want to make sure a string only has numeric characters, and IF it doesn't, I need to find the location in that string where the non-numeric character is located, and see what the value is

Comment: Yes I realize thats C#, same basic idea though

Comment: This will fail if a string represents a number below zero: eg. -1
This will be parsed as a number but what you want to actually check is if the string is digits-only. For finite accuracy and assumptions on string length, at least check if it's negative.

Answer (score 8):

Coding in VB.Net to check whether a string contains only numeric values or not.

```
If IsNumeric("your_text") Then
  MessageBox.Show("yes")
Else
  MessageBox.Show("no")
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

Use regular expressions:

```
Dim reg as New RegEx("^\d$")

If reg.IsMatch(myStringToTest) Then
  ' Numeric
Else
  ' Not
End If
```

UPDATE:

You could also use linq to accomplish the same task if you're doing it in VB.Net 2008/2010.

```
Dim isNumeric as Boolean = False

Dim stringQuery = From c In myStringToTest 
                          Where Char.IsDigit(c) 
                          Select c

If stringQuery.Count <> myStringToTest.Length Then isNumeric = False
```

Comment: Regular Expressions is the more elegant solution IMHO.  We use RE for most of our input validation and data scrubbing.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not wish to use RegEx, a simple check on each character with `char.IsNumber` works.

You can combine it with the `All` extension method (in C#, I don't know how to write it in VB.net):

```
string value = "78645655";
bool isValid = value.All(char.IsNumber);
```

Check out other `char` method, like `IsDigit`.

Comment: Unfortunately VB won't let you write something as elegant. You'd end up with `value.All(Function(c) Char.IsNumber(c))`

Answer (score 3):

2 other compact solutions :

Without LINQ :

```
Dim foo As String = "10004"
Array.Exists(foo.ToCharArray, Function(c As Char) Not Char.IsNumber(c))
```

With LINQ (just VB.Net equivalent of the C# version in another answer) :

```
foo.All(Function(c As Char) Char.IsNumber(c))
```

Answer (score 2):

Negative values haven't been mentioned, which `Integer.TryParse` would accept.

I prefer `UInteger.TryParse` which will reject a negative number. However, there is an additional check required in case the value starts with "+":

```
Dim test As String = "1444"
Dim outTest As UInteger
If Not test.StartsWith("+") AndAlso UInteger.TryParse(test, outTest) Then
    MessageBox.Show("It's just digits!")
End If
```

or `ULong.TryParse` for a larger number.

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching! See [this](http://www.example-code.com/vb/patternMatching.asp), [this](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/RegExNET_2.htm) (about.com) and [this](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/VB.Net/Regular-Expressions-in-.NET/1/) (VB.NET dev article).

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression or Integer.TryParse and I prefer the regular expression check

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you're looking at relatively short strings which will never have a number greater than the Max Int32 value, use Gage's solution.  If it's a variable length and sometimes you could overflow, use Regex (`System.Text.RegularExpressions`)

The regex for checking against just numbers is fairly routine: `^[0-9]+$`

Check [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for a very good explanation of Regex.